Matrix representation of conic sections
The quadratic equation $Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$, i. e. the equation satisfied by conic sections, can be represented in the form  $a^T Q a$, where $a$ is the column vector $$
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $Q$ is the symmetric matrix $$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & \frac B2 & \frac D2 \\
\frac B2 & C & \frac E2 \\
\frac D2 & \frac E2 & F \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, it is clear that this representation works, but what is the meaning of the z-coordinate of $a$ to be fixed to 1?

You have tagged it "projective geometry": and that is where the explanation lies.

Thanks for answering. I mean - I see it has something to deal with projective geometry, but I don't understand what. That's why I asked for it.

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section esp where it talks about conics in projective space.

Thank you again, but any "not redirecting" answer would be much more appreciated :)

The reason why we choose $z=1$ is because this is the standard way of going from projective plane to the affine plane.
The projective plane is defined as the lines through the origin in 3-space ($k^3,$ where $k$ is your field, let's take $k={\Bbb R}$). Then intersecting with the plane $z=1$ identified as the usual $xy$-plane works on an equation level as well. A homogeneous equation of degree $2$ in $x,y,z$ defines a cone in $k^3$ with cone point through the origin. Any curve given by an equation can be homogenized to  make a homogeneous one making up the cone of lines through the origin and on the curve in the $z=1$ identified $xy$-plane. Putting $z=1$ in the homogeneous one goes the other way.
This gives you the best of both worlds. In the projective plane, there's one smooth conic section, depending on where you put the "line at infinity". Moving the $z=1$ plane also moves the line at infinity. But keeping the $z=1$ fixed, and therefore also the line at infinity, you can get the same effect by changing the equation. I.e. in one sense there really is only one smooth conic section, the cone itself.
Original answer:
A conic section is a section of a plane with a cone. Without loss of generality, you can translate a general cone to have the cone point (the singularity) at the origin, and the plane can be taken to be $z=1,$ while only skipping a few degenerate conics in the finite. So the system of a general cone through the origin and intersecting plane in space
$$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx z+ Ey z+ F z^2= 0\\z=1$$
is one way of capturing all conic sections, and explaining the name at the same time.

Thank you for your kind answer. However, the reason to choose z = 1 is still not clear to me

@DavideMasi See the edit

Thank you very much!
